# Observable unsubscribe method is not available

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

I'm trying to unsubscribe upon ngOnDestroy

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.user.unsubscribe()
  }
```

However unsubscribe does not exist on type Observable

I'm subscribing the method upon `loginUser` function

```
  loginUser(): void {
    const raw = this.userForm.getRawValue();
    let post = {
      username: raw.username,
      password: raw.password
    };
    console.log(post);
    this.user.subscribe(err => {
      this.error = err;
    });
    this.store.dispatch(new initLogin(post));
  }
```

**loginComponent(full code)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { initLogin } from "../../../store/actions/auth.actions";
import { Store, select } from "@ngrx/store";
import { State, loginError } from "../../../store/reducers";
import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login-form",
  templateUrl: "./login-form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login-form.component.css"]
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  userForm: FormGroup;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  user: Observable<any>;
  error: Observable<any>;
  isAuthenticated: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(""),
      password: new FormControl("")
    });
    this.user = this.store.pipe(select(loginError));
  }
  // can handle validations
  loginUser(): void {
    const raw = this.userForm.getRawValue();
    let post = {
      username: raw.username,
      password: raw.password
    };
    console.log(post);
    this.user.subscribe(err => {
      this.error = err;
    });
    this.store.dispatch(new initLogin(post));
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.user.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the subscription to a variable.

Try:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
.....
userSubscription: Subscription;

...
this.userSubscription = this.user.subscribe(err => {
      if (this) {
        this.error = err;
      }
    });

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: What is Subscription supposed to be ? Could it be `any` instead of `subscription`

Comment: Yes, it can be `any` but I have edited my answer to specify where you can get it from.

Comment: thanks this fixed the error, will accept answer in 5 min.

Comment: however i do have a question, why do i get error  `Cannot read property 'error' of undefined` upon logging out and being redirected to the login page. I thought ngOnDestroy would fix this isue.

Comment: on loginUser, im assigning the error message from ngrx store to `this.error`. on ngOnDestory im unsubscribing the data, which means this.error whould be a null value. Instead im getting `Cannot read property 'error' of undefined` Would you have an idea why is this the case ?

Comment: Is the error message coming from the line `this.error = err`? or from the `HTML`?

Comment: I have provided a hacky way of doing it with an `if(this)` statement but that should not be needed. Supposedly the subscription is alive but the component is dead. But we unsubscribed on the `onDestroy`.